# Is there a way to hide text following tags with CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have `<div><strike>Stuff I want</strike> Stuff I don't want</div>`. It is what it is. No way around it.

Is there a way I can hide the "Stuff I don't want" with CSS?

Like for example I can show the "Stuff I don't want" alone easily enough. with a `.strike { display: none; }` but is there a way to show only the "Stuff I want'?

Comment: Hide as in `display: none` (removed from the flow of the document) or hide as in `visibility: hidden` (still in flow of the document, but cannot be read)?

Comment: Yeah I would need it removed from the document flow, thanks.

Comment: Funny you would use `strike` to denote content that should remain visible...

Comment: Not my choice. One of those times when you're forced to work with what you're given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
div { font-size: 0; }
strike { font-size: 10px; }
```

Better:

```
div { visibility: hidden; }
strike { visibility: visible; }
```

Comment: Given the OP's use case perhaps the first is better.

Comment: Perfect. First one worked like a charm. Thank you. Checkmark in T minus four minutes.